# Update reused BackboneJS views with jQuery

Tags: backbone.js, view

I have a secondary navigation that is used on some views but not all. Thus I include the following in views that use the secondary navigation which works without a problem:

```
  setupNavigationSecondary: =>
    view = new App.Views.Users.NavigationSecondary(navigation_active: ".navigation-secondary-manage")
    @$(".navigation-secondary").replaceWith(view.render().el)
```

You will notice I pass a reference for "navigation_active" which tells the secondary navigation which menu item to mark as active. The secondary navigation view has the following to add an "active" class to the right menu item:

```
  navigation_active: ""

  initialize: (options) ->
    @navigation_active = options.navigation_active

  setActiveNavigationItem: =>
    if @navigation_active.length
      $(document).ready =>
        $(@navigation_active).parent().addClass('active')

  render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template())

    @setActiveNavigationItem()

    return this
```

**The problem:**

Everything works fine when the page is first loaded directly via the URL in the browser, i.e. the correct secondary navigation item has the "active" class. If I started somewhere else or I go elsewhere and return to a view with the secondary navigation - the views on-screen are updated after the '$(@navigation_active).parent().addClass('active')' function is executed and thus no menu items have the "active" class.

So, how do I update the active navigation item after the secondary navigation view has loaded?

Comment: Further research, I've found that I should probably not recreate the view in the setupNavigationSecondary() function. I'm probably making multiple instances of the same view ....

Comment: why are the views on-screen updated after the '$(@navigation_active).parent().addClass('active')' function is executed?

Comment: When the router is triggered, the new view is initiated. By placing an alert message after $(@navigation_active).parent().addClass('active'), I can see the "active" class is added to the view I'm currently using. As soon as I click "Ok" on the alert message, the next view is loaded which kills the view currently displaying .... after typing this, I just worked it out.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot one important item, issue resolved now.

```
  setActiveNavigationItem: =>
    if @navigation_active.length
      $(document).ready =>
        $(@navigation_active).parent().addClass('active')
```

Should be

```
  setActiveNavigationItem: =>
    if @navigation_active.length
        // line removed - we don't need to wait for the DOM to be ready
        @$(@navigation_active).parent().addClass('active') // @ symbol
```